# BTX nitration work-up

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, extraction

I'm trying to understand washing step in a btx nitration process. In all these processes the work-up streams are very similar. The reaction mixture passes from the nitrator to a separator or centrifuge, and aqueous spent acid is fed to the recycle loop via a concentrator or strength adjustment stage as appropriate. Crude nitrobenzene, as
the top layer, is passed through a series of washer — separators. [image]

In washer—separator 1, mineral acids and Nitrogen dioxide is removed with water. [image]

In washer—separator 2, residual acid removed and weakly acidic byproducts like nitrophenols and nitrocresols with are removed with dilute alkali [image]

In washer—separator 3, water is used for further extraction. And my question is why? nitrophenolate sodium, nitrocresolate sodium, Sodium sulfate and Sodium nitrate are all in the aqueous phase and should have been separated in the first two steps.